# Knockout.js two way binding between multi select and delimited string

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

Just discovering knockout so please point out stupidity if I missed something here.  I currently have a multiple select bound to an observable in knockout.

```
<select class="form-control" id="SithSelect" data-bind="attr: { 'data-has-value': (Sith() ? true : false) }, selectedOptions: Sith() ? Sith().split('|') : '' " placeholder="The dark side" multiple>
    <option disabled></option>
    <option value="Darth Vader">Darth Vader</option>
    <option value="Darth Maul">Darth Maul</option>
    <option value="Darth Bane">Darth Bane</option>
</select>
```

Where "Sith" is an observable string value.

When I manually add the string value "Darth Vader|Darth Maul" in the database and the value eventually gets down to the client side, the multi select correctly shows two values selected.

However, if I change the values, how do I then combine the selected values back to a pipe delimited string stored in the observable?

From what I've tried I can sort this by having an observable array that the select is bound to and then re-construct the pipe delimited string on save to the database.  This solution smells a bit funny when I look over the code tho because it feels tightly coupled to the individual select element (this is the only one on the page that uses a pipe delimited string from the DB).

Have I missed something in managing to do two-way binding between a multi select and a delimited string?  Rather, is there a way to do the opposite of

```
selectedOptions: Sith() ? Sith().split('|') : ''
```

when assigning the multiple selected options back to the observable value in the binding?

UPDATE: The question has been narrowed down to:

Is there something inbuilt to knockout that I can place within a binding, that can handle the read/write functions of a computed value, so that I can write it inline, rather than having to create a separate computed observable value?

Comment: I think you are approaching this the wrong way.  Selected Options should be an observable array set in the viewModle

Comment: Yes I understand that, as mentioned I did manage to bind to an observable array and then reconstruct the pipe delim'd string but having a specific piece of code to reconstruct the string feels dirty compared to how generic the rest of my bindings are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectedOptions` should be array or an observable array. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html

There's no way for Knockout to know how to save data back to `Sith`, when you're passing to it some data calculated from `Sith`.

You should use `ko.observableArray` or just `ko.observable` with array value. But you'll need to synchronize your string value and array value. Instead of manually supporting two subscriptions (str=>arr, arr=>str) you can use writable computed (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html):

```html
<select data-bind="selectedOptions: sith">...</select>
```

```js
vm.sithString = ko.observable('');
vm.sith = ko.computed({
  read: function() { return vm.sithString().split('|'); },
  write: function(arr) { vm.sithString(arr.join('|')); }
});
```

**UPDATE**

> Is there something inbuilt to knockout that I can place within a binding, that can handle the read/write functions of a computed value, so that I can write it inline, rather than having to create a separate computed observable value?

This is the exact purpose of ViewModel in MVVM. You have model, which is you pure data (well, you have to store it in observables, but anyway). You have bindings, which are purely UI things. And you have mediator between them ViewModel to convert data and events between them. Writable computed in this example represents ViewModel-Model relations.

Writable computeds is much more general and flexible mechanism than `write`/`read` functions per binding.

**UPDATE 2**
Well, `selectedOptions` is not the easiest binding to sit on top of. The way is to attach exactly the same computed to element and replace `valueAccessor` in binding functions. Code is straightforward, but requires knowledge of how bingings work:

```html
var selectedOptions = ko.bindingHandlers['selectedOptions'];
ko.bindingHandlers['pipedOptions'] = {
  after: selectedOptions.after, /* ['options', 'foreach'] */
  init: function(el, va) {
    var obsv = va();

    var mediator = ko.computed({
      read: function() { return obsv().split('|'); },
      write: function(arr) { obsv(arr.join('|')); }
    });

    ko.utils.domData.set(el, 'pipedOptions.mediator', mediator);

    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    args[1] = function() { return mediator; };
    selectedOptions.init.apply(this, args);
  },
  update: function(el, va) {
    var mediator = ko.utils.domData.get(el, 'pipedOptions.mediator');
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    args[1] = function() { return mediator; };
    selectedOptions.update.apply(this, args);
  }
};
```

If you need more complex behavior take a look at components.

Comment: Yes I came up with something similar but that seems much cleaner, thanks.  I guess my question was more, is there something inbuilt to knockout that I can place within a binding, that can handle the read/write functions of a computed value, so that I can write it inline, rather than having to create a separate computed observable value?

I will update the question

Comment: I think a custom binding is the way forward - I'm doing further reading

Comment: @LordJam why would you need a custom binding? Standard options is exactly what you want: get/update elements in `<select>`. Don't put your model logic into bindings.

Comment: "Writable computed in this example represents ViewModel-Model relations" - Very helpful to describe it in this manner.   It;s cleared a few things up.

"Why would you need a custom binding" - I guess the idea of flexibility isn't the main driver here.  On subsequent pages/forms we will be using a similar thing for comma delim'd values and pipe delim'd values from the DB, so the appeal of having a custom binding to manage this has a bit more sway.

"Don't put your model logic into bindings" - ? Just for best practice? Please expand on this.  Why not?

Comment: @LordJam everything is simply less coupled and more flexible that way. Can you adapt standard `options` for your needs? Yes. Can you adapt you custom binding for anything else? No. In your case, since we know the context now, custom binding is ok solution (but, please, built it on top of standart `options`). I'll update my answer. Also take look at components.

Comment: Thanks.  The more I think about it the more I think I will need a component, but this is the best thing I've come across.  Thanks again